# Change QProgressbar background and chunk image programatically

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qprogressbar

I need to change the background and chunk image of a QProgressBar element programatically. I already know that I can achieve this by applying a StyleSheet with a given image url during runtime. 
The problem in my case is that I can't use local files but rather have to download the file during runtime. Thus I must be able to set the background image of a QProgressBar using a QImage/QPixmap/QIcon (or any other appropriate) object without using a Stylesheet.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO , What have you tried till now... ???

Comment: I ended up writing my own Progressbar with two given QPixmap objects (one for the background and one for the progress overlay). To achieve the correct look of the Widget, I had to override the paintEvent method of QWidget and paint the control myself.
I will write an answer to my question with the belonging code later.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct answer to set styleSheet of QProgressBar:

```
 QString style=NULL;
setValue(40);
style.append("QProgressBar{border: 0px solid grey;background-image:url("/UrlImage Background/abc.png");background-color:transparent;}");
style.append("QProgressBar::chunk {background:url("/UrlImage Background/chunkimage.png");}");
setStyleSheet(style);
```